# Unity, IntField in GUI?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how can i edit Int value with `GUI.TextField` or anything for editing Using A Field for Int in GUI?
i can't use String with code `PlayerControl.Spawn(Int X, Int Y, Int Z)`
My Code is

```
namespace MonoInjector
{
using AssemblyCSharp;
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;

public class CheatGUI3 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool ChatSpamTextOn = false;
    private bool DrawGUIOn = false;
    private int CoordinateX = 0;
    private int CoordinateY = 0;
    private int CoordinateZ = 0;
    private static CheatGUI2 cheatgui;
    private static Rect windowRect = new Rect(10f, 350f, 150f, 180f);
    private void DrawGUI()
    {
        windowRect = GUI.Window(0, windowRect, new GUI.WindowFunction(this.DrawGUIWindow), "Black3D");
    }
    private void DrawGUIWindow(int id)
    {
        int num = 0x16;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(2f, (float)num, 125f, 20f), "Coordinate X");
        num += 0x16;
        CoordinateX = GUI.TextField(new Rect(10, 10, 200, 20), CoordinateX, 40);
        num += 14;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(2f, (float)num, 125f, 20f), "Coordinate Y");
        num += 0x16;
        CoordinateY = GUI.TextField(new Rect(10, 10, 200, 20), CoordinateY, 40);
        num += 14;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(2f, (float)num, 125f, 20f), "Coordinate Z");
        num += 0x16;
        CoordinateZ = GUI.TextField(new Rect(10, 10, 200, 20), CoordinateZ, 40);
        num += 14;
    }
    private void HandleTeleport()
    {
        PlayerControl.Spawn(CoordinateX, CoordinateY, CoordinateZ);
    }
```

there is error

> Error 161 The best overloaded method match for 'UnityEngine.GUI.TextField(UnityEngine.Rect, string, int)' has some invalid arguments

and error

> Error 165 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'

and error

> Error 163 Argument 3: cannot convert from 'int' to 'UnityEngine.GUIStyle'

edit: i can't use String for CoordinateX etc

Answer (score 1):

The first error message about the conversion from `int` to `string` can be solved fairly easily as below:

```
CoordinateX = GUI.TextField(new Rect(10, 10, 200, 20), CoordinateX.ToString(), 40);
```

The issue is that `CoordinateX` is of type `int` and you pass it to a method which expects a `string`.

Last but not least, you have also to cast the result of `GUI.TextField` to an `int`, since it's type is string.

```
CoordinateX = (int)GUI.TextField(new Rect(10, 10, 200, 20)
             , CoordinateX.ToString()
             , 40);
```

Comment: Error 203 Cannot convert type 'int' to 'UnityEngine.GUIStyle'
          now there is this error

Comment: @MateuszZasadowski please check my update and read this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.TextField.html. There are all the overloads of the method you use and I think that the above does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
 CoordinateX = Mathf.RoundToInt(GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(10, 10, 200, 20), CoordinateX , minValue, maxValue));
```